# What's the best way to create an engine for an engine in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working with an engine in Rails and I'd like to extend its functionality with additional models and controllers in a modular format.  My idea was to create an "engine for an engine."  Is this the best approach?  If so, how would you achieve this?  If not, what would be a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

What about creating an other Engine that you would mount in your main application in addition to the first one ?

```
CoreEngine
ExtendedCoreEngine
```

Are your additional models and controllers specific to the Engine and have nothing to do the any Rails application your engine is mounted in ?